# How to pass state during Nest.js Authentication flow

Tags: oauth, passport.js, nestjs

while performing a Google OAuth flow, it is possible to pass an encrypted state (base64) that will be passed as parameter to the final callback. This was useful when you want to redirect your user to a specific page for example. (https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server)

Is it possible to use the OAuth state with the Nest.js authentication library? It seems that the state parameter is ignored and I can't find anything on the documentation.

```
@Injectable()
export class GoogleStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'google') {
  constructor(readonly configService: ConfigService) {
    super({
      clientID: configService.get('google.clientId'),
      clientSecret: configService.get('google.clientSecret'),
      callbackURL: `${configService.get('apiUri')}${configService.get('google.callbackUrl')}`,
      passReqToCallback: true,
      scope: ['profile', 'email'],
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

To solve this, I added an `authenticate` function to the class that sets the state value.

```
authenticate(req, options) {
  options.state = 'your state value here'
  super.authenticate(req, options)
}
```

disclaimer: I was trying to achieve something similar to what you described and this approach worked for me, but I'm not sure if it's the "correct" way to handle this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'll wait for a real solution from NestJS but this work and is what we ended up doing.

Comment: **Important for those reading this answer** you must **not** set `store: true` or `state: true` in the strategy configuration for this to work. It would've saved me a half hour to realize this earlier

Answer (score 1):

```js
@Injectable()
export class GoogleAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('google') {
  getAuthenticateOptions(context: ExecutionContext) {
    // you can get access to the request object.
    // const request = this.getRequest(context);

    return {
      state: `my-custom-state_${Date.now()}`,
    };
  }
}
```

and in your `auth.controller` you can get access to this `state` param though query values.

```js
@UseGuards(GoogleAuthGuard)
@Get('google/callback')
async googleCallback(@Query('state') state: string): Promise<string> {
  console.log({ state });

  return state;
}
```